# Multiple inheritance with Qt classes

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class A that inherits QGraphicsItem, and another class B that inherits QgraphicsLineItem. How can B inherit class A

class A : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem {

}

class B : public QObject, public QGraphicsLineItem {
}

How can A be inherited by B?

My problem is as Under:

Class with virtual clone method()

```
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class getEntity : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
   getEntity(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
   virtual ~getEntity() {}

   virtual getEntity *clone() { return 0; }
};
```

stack.h

```
#include <QStack>

#include "getEntity.h"

class clipboardStack
{
public:
    static clipboardStack *instance()
    {
        if (!inst)
            inst = new clipboardStack;
        return inst;
    }

    void push(getEntity *entity)
    {
        clips.push(entity);
    }

    getEntity *pasteEntity()
    {
        if (clips.count() == 0)
            return 0;
        return clips.last();
    }

    getEntity *pop()
    {
        if (clips.count() == 0)
            return 0;
        return clips.pop();
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return clips.empty();
    }

private:
    QStack<getEntity *> clips;
    static clipboardStack *inst;
};
```

circle.h

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

#include "qmath.h"
#include "operations/getEntity.h"
#include "operations/clipboardstack.h"

class Circle : QGraphicsItem , public getEntity
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Circle(QObject *parent = 0) : getEntity(parent) {}
    Circle(int, QPointF, QPointF);
    Circle(int, QPointF, qreal);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter,
                       const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                       QWidget *widget);
    enum { Type = UserType + 3 };
    int type() const;
    int id;

    QPointF centerP, endP;
    qreal radius;

    getEntity *clone();

private:
    QVector<QPointF> stuff;
};
```

//Problem with Line
line.h

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>

#include "operations/getEntity.h"
class Line : public QObject, public QGraphicsLineItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Line(QObject *parent = 0) : getLine(parent) {}
    Line(int, QPointF, QPointF);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter,
                       const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                       QWidget *widget);
    enum { Type = UserType + 2 };
    int type() const;
    int id;

    QPointF startP, endP;



private:
    QVector<QPointF> stuff;
};
```

cadgraphicsscene.cpp

```
 void CadGraphicsScene::cutEntity(getEntity *obj)
{
    removeItem(obj);
    clipboardStack::instance()->push(obj);
}

void CadGraphicsScene::copyEntity(getEntity *obj)
{
    clipboardStack::instance()->push(obj->clone());
}

void CadGraphicsScene::pasteEntity(const QPointF &pos)
{
    getEntity *pasteEntity = clipboardStack::instance()->pop();
    if (pasteEntity)
    {
        addItem(dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem *>(pasteEntity));
        pasteEntity->setPos(pos);
        pasteEntity->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
        pasteEntity->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
        mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandAdd(this, pasteEntity));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need such an evil inheritance?

Comment: The whole scenerio is: I have different entities that can be drawn in Graphics View. For them I have different classes. Like circle, ellipse and point are inherited from QgraphicsItem, Line from QgraphicsLineItem and Text from QgraphicsTextItem. I wanted to have cut, copy paste functionality. For that I made a class inheriting QGraphicsItem, with virtual clone method. I can successfully cut, copy paste circle, line and ellipse. But facing problem with Line and Text. Should make another class with virtual clone inheriting QgraphicsLineItem now?

Comment: Would maybe a common base class, which has nothing to do with QGraphicsItem make sense?

Comment: Or How can I deal with inheritance.

Comment: @Bowdzone didn't get you?

Comment: One base class for all kindes of your items handlings the cut/copy/paste: `class A: QObject { copy/cut/paste stuff}`. As many classes for the individual operations as you need `class B: QGraphicsItem, A {}`, `class C: QGraphicsLineItem, A {}`

Comment: I will do and report that. Will that be fine?

Comment: @user3877872, but maybe it worth to fix problem with rather cloning your Line and Text objects than messing with inheritance? You can describe which kind of problem you have (with code examples), and maybe it can be solved much easier?

Comment: I have edited the post with the code too.

Comment: @Bowdzone when I do this, it would give me the error in stack class added in the post:/ I guess.

Comment: Can you help me please? I just want to have cut, copy paste functionality with all the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QGraphicsObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsobject.html) instead of QGraphicsItem, which provides the required signals / slots mechanism for you, without the need for multiple inheritance.

You also mention in  your comment:-

> [inheriting] Line from QgraphicsLineItem and Text from QgraphicsTextItem

Rather than extending QGraphicsLineItem and QGraphicsTextItem, it would be better if you inherit from QGraphicsItem or QGraphicsObject, as you do for circle, ellipse and point.